# What is the best way to notify when download is completed with Download Manager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager, android-toast, android-snackbar

I would like to achieve to show a snack bar or a toast when download is competed but I don't know hot to get status of download..Please help me.

```kotlin
    private fun downloadManager(url: String?) {
        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url)).apply {
                allowScanningByMediaScanner()
                setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                    URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, null)
                )
            }
            ContextCompat.getSystemService(this, DownloadManager::class.java)!!
                .enqueue(request)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should add a broadcast receiver for DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE. Then in onReceive() display the toast.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for the comments. I understand that I need to add ```ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE``` but how can I implement this? Please help me.

Comment: If you google that action with downloadmanager...